# Best storage for access token?

Tags: apex, cache

What would be the best place to store access token and similar data in a Salesforce application? My apex class retrieves some data which is used for client authorization on some external API (it doesn't use OAuth2 or any standardized protocol, it has some custom protocol) and I need to keep it somewhere.

I was considering [Session Cache](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_cache_Session.htm#apex_class_cache_Session), but it is only supported in Enterprise and Unlimited and Performance editions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best choice outside of Named Credentials would be to store the token in a [Custom Setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm). Make sure that the field is encrypted [using best practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Storing_Secrets) so that the session can't be hijacked by users with sufficient access to see the token. Session Cache is a poor choice anyways, because it can be invalidated at any time, so you might end up needing to arbitrarily login again.

Edit: List Custom Settings have been deprecated. One might consider using [Custom Metadata Types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_about.htm&type=5), which allows you to create a field that supports more than 255 characters for systems that have really long tokens.

Comment: A big issue here is that its not possible to store a token that is longer that 255 chars :(

Comment: char count on Marketing Cloud token I tried to save using this method was 306

Comment: @Cleverlemming This is a relatively old answer. An updated version would say that Custom Metadata would probably be more appropriate; you can create a field that supports up to 131kb worth of text, easily large enough to handle practically any token.

Comment: checked into custom metadata types and SF recommends not using them (or custom settings) for auth tokens outside of a managed package (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Metadata_CustomMetadata.htm). The following suggestion would make life easier: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003apqQAA. (@sfdcfox's extended discussion of token storage is useful: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149921/where-to-store-token-auth)

Comment: @Cleverlemming True enough. Thanks for the idea suggestion. As far as storing secrets, they should *definitely* be encrypted if this is your only option, as it is non-trivial for normal users to get access to the necessary key material to decipher the data. Until/unless we have a better solution (NC would definitely be ideal), we have to work with what we have.

Comment: Even the only bulletproof solution is the protected custom metadata/setting, I will be very careful following this lead since it's adding a lot of complexity.
  
Worth mentioned that you can create/update custom metadata currently only via the metadata API like not being able to see the debug log output and having to maintain the code as a separately managed package.

Regarding  Custom settings, you can still use but only with a hierarchy type.