# Using Named Credentials With 3rd Party Authorization Token

Tags: api, authorization, external-services

Trying to use point and click

> External Services

but unsuccessful with

> Named Credential authorization.

A 3rd party service just requires the Authorization Token be sent with request. Not seeing any options in Named Credentials to use this? Before being pointed to creating an Apex Class or Connected App I want to confirm that the point and click approach for this is NOT possible today.

[Saw this post a few years ago here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149921/where-to-store-token-auth) which seems to confirm the above but not clearly.

API I'm trying to use is pretty basic [RealValidation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Pn-GVvGTbYLW12NmlyRUpsUnc/view). Seems like rest of External Service piece may be working when used in a Flow.

Comment: Not dup as Im trying to create Named Credential, not using URL endpoint. This is starting with a Named Credential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on RealValidation doc in your question, this 3rd party service doesn't appear to use a standardized authentication protocol, it wants a token (which they equate to a password) to be sent in as one of the query parameters in the request

[image: RealValidation API]

Named Credentials won't do much for you in this case. Stick the value of their token into a protected custom setting or protected custom metadata type then have your Apex code dynamically build the request URL.

Comment: Its an auth token for the API. They dont allow name and password for API.

Comment: @user2451 It's still their own, proprietary (and hilariously bad) token scheme so Named Credentials won't help you.

Comment: The point is, if you can only merge these parameters into the URI, you can't use `NamedCredential`. If you could merge them into headers or request body, you'd be good to go. As such, you'll need to use some other tool (e.g. `Hierarchy Custom Setting`).