# Programmatically edit authentication parameter of external credentials

Tags: apex, security, namedcredentials, jwt, externalcredentials

I was wondering if updating an authentication parameter of an External Credential was possible from an Apex method.

The main goal of this function would be to programmatically store an access token which is according to Salesforce the best practice but I can't find a way to change the External Credential / Named Credential from an Apex code.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please edit your question and explain your goals.

Comment: Hi @identigral thank you for your comment. This is not an XY Problem as my X problem is to look for the most suitable place to store an access token and according to sfdcfox's response on (Where to Store Token Auth?)[https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149921/where-to-store-token-auth] , the best place would be a named credential / external credential. Here my problem would be how to set this credential from an Apex code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using the `ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.patchCredential()` method. You can find the documentation of the method [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_NamedCredentials_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_NamedCredentials_patchCredential_4).

As an example, this code updates a External Named credential called `ExternalCred` with:

- Custom authentication protocol
- A single principal called `Authentication`
- One encrypted autentication parameter inside the principal called `Secret`

```
ConnectApi.CredentialInput newCredentials = new ConnectApi.CredentialInput();
newCredentials.authenticationProtocol = ConnectApi.CredentialAuthenticationProtocol.Custom;

Map<String, ConnectApi.CredentialValueInput> creds = new Map<String, ConnectApi.CredentialValueInput>();
ConnectApi.CredentialValueInput secret = new ConnectApi.CredentialValueInput();
clientIdValue.encrypted = true;
clientIdValue.value = secretValue;
creds.put('secret', secret);

newCredentials.credentials = creds;
newCredentials.externalCredential = 'ExternalCred'
newCredentials.principalType = ConnectApi.CredentialPrincipalType.NamedPrincipal;
newCredentials.principalName = 'Authentication';
ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.patchCredential(newCredentials);
```

You will need to tweak it depending on the authorization type and your special needs.